# Why do we need IAudioRenderClient Interface

Tags: windows, audio, com, wasapi

This question is about windows audio session API. After reading microsoft's sample code, I find that after getting a IAudioClient, "GetService" Method is called on it to obtain a IAudioRenderClient. And then the GetBuffer and ReleaseBuffer method of IAudioRenderClient is called to add buffer to be played.

My question:

1. Why is IAudioRenderClient necessary, why not just put the GetBuffer and ReleaseBuffer method directly in IAudioClient? Namely when is the case we need multiple IAudioRenderClient for a single IAudioClient?
2. Since when we play audio, we always need a IAudioClient, and on this IAudioClient we call GetService to obtain a IAudioRenderClient, we don't have any chance to call CoCreateInstance()  to create IAudioRenderClient do we? Then why do we need a IID for IAudioRenderClient?

==============================================================================

After some more reading, I think IAudioClient can be a IAudioRenderClient or a IAudioCaptureClient. But another question arise, why we call GetService to obtain IAudioRenderClient but not QueryInterface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because `IAudioCaptureClient` also has `GetBuffer` and `ReleaseBuffer`. If you put `GetBuffer` and `ReleaseBuffer` on `IAudioClient`, then how would you know whether you are dealing with capture or render buffers? This approach also stops the `IAudioClient` from getting cluttered with too many methods for all the possible services. (This is called the "[interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)" and it is considered good design).
2. You don't use `CoCreateInstance` because your system could have many soundcards installed. How would it know which `IAudioRenderClient` you wanted if you passed ion the IID of `IAudioRenderClient`?